# Javascript Conditional Dynamic Form Not Inputting Fields

Tags: javascript, cascadingdropdown, dynamic-forms

I have the following form. It's purpose is to see what state is selected and pass that value to a script that will dynamically add more dropdown boxes with an auto-incrementing ID for storage in a database. I have no script errors but the dynamic fields will not pop into place. Incidentally, this is based off Rob's work here, http://www.web-design-talk.co.uk/58/adding-unlimited-form-fields-with-jquery-mysql/#comment-70752. Can anyone see any faults with what I'm doing.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Form</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib/jquery/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<form id="Form" name="Form" method="post" action="Form.php">
<fieldset>
<legend>Form</legend>

<label>Operations State: </label>
<select name="StateID" id="StateID">
<option value="">Select a State</option>
<option value="CA">CA</option>
<option value="NY">NY</option>
<option value="PA">PA</option>
</select>
<br>
<div id="container">
<p id="add_field">
<label><a href="#" onclick="getClass(StateID.value)">Add A Class Code</a></label>Please select a Class Code
</p>
</div>

</fieldset>
</form>

<script>
var i = 0;

function getClass(str){
var StateID = $("#StateID").val();

$('p#add_field').on('click', function(){
i += 1;

$('#container').before
if (StateID == "CA"){
    ('<label>Select a Class Code</label>' + '<select name="ClassCode[]" id="ClassCode_' + i + '">' + '<option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option>' + '</select><br>')
}

else if (StateID == "NY"){
    ('<label>Select a Class Code</label>' + '<select name="ClassCode[]" id="ClassCode_' + i + '">' + '<option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option>' + '</select><br>')
}

else if (StateID == "PA"){
    ('<label>Select a Class Code</label>' + '<select name="ClassCode[]" id="ClassCode_' + i + '">' + '<option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option>' + '</select><br>')
}

else{
}

});     
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance!

After some edits, I came up with the following...

```
<script>

var i = 0;

function getClass(){
var StateID = $("#StateID").val();

$('p#add_field').on('click', function(){
i += 1;

if (StateID == "CA"){
$('#container').before(
'<label>Select a Class Code</label>' + '<select name="ClassCode[]" id="ClassCode_' + i + '">' + '<option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option>' + '</select><br>')
}

else if (StateID == "NY"){
$('#container').before(
'<label>Select a Class Code</label>' + '<select name="ClassCode[]" id="ClassCode_' + i + '">' + '<option value="4">4</option><option value="5">5</option><option value="6">6</option>' + '</select><br>')
}

else if (StateID == "PA"){
$('#container').before(
'<label>Select a Class Code</label>' + '<select name="ClassCode[]" id="ClassCode_' + i + '">' + '<option value="7">7</option><option value="8">8</option><option value="9">9</option>' + '</select><br>')
}   

else{
}

})
}

</script>
```

This version does see the StateID and changes the dropdown boxes accordingly with each new addition. The only issue is that along with auto-incrementing the ID (eg. ClassCode_1, ClassCode_2, etc), it is also incrementing the number of fields output to the page. If that can be figured out, it will be awesome!

Comment: You should be seeing errors in the JavaScript console.

Comment: There are errors in your code , mostly in the way function is declared. Try to use firebug or developement tools and you most probably will see errors

Comment: I just updated the <script> portion to where it returns no errors in Chrome's Console but it doesn't create new fields either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a fair amount trying to happen here; I'd simplify things down to basics so you can see what's going on.

You've got what is essentially a click handler (`onclick` in the HTML) that seems to be trying to attach other click handlers to a paragraph tag. I guess that's not what you're going for. You're using jQuery, so there's no point adding an onclick attribute to your click when jQuery can manage all that for you.

The steps should be:

1. On the click of the link, check what the value of the state dropdown is.
2. Remove any dropdowns that have been previously injected into the DOM.
3. Inject a new dropdown into the DOM, with options depending on the value.

Take a **look at this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7QYgg/2/)**, which hopefully strips everything back to basics. This does what I think you're after, though I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the incrementing IDs - I'll have to leave that one to your judgment!

Comment: Right. Your fiddle is cool. This one is based off http://www.web-design-talk.co.uk/58/adding-unlimited-form-fields-with-jquery-mysql/#comment-70752 which creates dynamic input fields to a form. I was trying to take that and modify it so that it adds select boxes based on a particular StateID.

Comment: I played a bit with your design and got it doing exactly what I needed. Here's the Fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/7QYgg/15/. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You're setting up your "getClass()" function incorrectly. The way your code is written, it's being passed as an argument to jQuery, and it is *not* being declared as a global function. So just declare it:

```
function getClass(str) {
  // ...
}
```

Once you do that, I *think* you'll want to change the code that adds content so that it's adding a complete single DOM element. Surround your `<label>` and `<select>` with a `<span>` or something.

Also, "i" needs to be a global variable, or else it'll start over at 0 on each call to the function. Move its declaration to outside of "getClass".

Comment: I did try setting up the function like that originally with the i outside. What was happening then, regardless of i's position was that it would increment the number of fields it created rather than the number of the ID. It's weird. As of now, if I take out all of the conditional stuff leaving just the following code, it will create new form fields with the intended incremented ID's. The moment I try to add conditions, it just stops.

Comment: `$(function getClass(str){`
`    var StateID = str;`
` var i = 0;`
` $('p#add_field').on('click', function(){`
`    i += 1;`
    
`    $('#container').before`
`  ('<label>Select a Class Code</label>' + '<select name="ClassCode[]" id="ClassCode_' + i + '">' + '<option value="1">1</option><option value="2">2</option><option value="3">3</option>' + '</select><br>')`

`    });`  
`    })`

Comment: There are other problems too - those state names that you're comparing are variables that don't appear to exist.

Comment: I can see the states when doing jQuery(StateID).val();. I pass the value when the link is clicked and the function picks it up. I had a rudimentary version working with text only before that printed the name of the state chosen when the link was clicked. Even then though, it showed the state when clicked the first time, the previous state AND new state the second time, the two previous states AND new state the third time, etc.

Comment: Oh wait. It did drop the StateID. Weird.